# how to guarantee that all requests in the react component method will be completed by a certain point

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have a class react component that has a fetchData method in which the api is called several times
I need to wait in the componentDidMount method for several API calls to be completed in the fetchData method

```
class ApartmentPage extends PureComponent {
//here is some code
    componentDidMount() {
        

        this.fetchData().then(() => {
        
            setTimeout(() => { // how to do it without setTimeout
                // here this.props must be updated by fetches
            console.log('data1, data2, data3', this.props); 
 
            const data = {
                data1: this.props?.data1 // +
                data2: this.props.data2, // +
                data3: this.props.data3, // +
              };


            sendData(data);

            }, 500);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.warn('error', error);
        });
    }


{
        const {
           id,
           fetchData1,
           fetchData2,
           fetchData3,
        } = this.props;

        let promisses = [];
        
        this.fetchSomeData();
        promisses.push(**this.fetchData1()**);
        this.fetchSomeOtherData();
        this.fetchSomeOtherData2();
        
       

        fetchSomeData3({
            id,
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.list && res.list.length) {

                    promisses.push(**fetchData2(id)**);
                }
        });


        if(Cookies.get('user_name')) promisses.push(**fetchData3(id)**);
        //promisses === [undefined, Promise] 
        return Promise.all(promisses).then(() => {
            console.log(this.props, '123777');
          });
    }
}
```

I tried to add setTimeout and array promisses but i got confused

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with checking that all my fetches I need to be resolved by sendData call have Promise returned

for example I made fetch function look like

```
fetchData1() {
        const { id, name } = this.props;

        return fetchApartment(id, name).then(response => {
            if (response.data) {
                this.setState({ data});

                return Promise.resolve()
            }
        });
    }
```

before it was:

```
fetchData1() {
        const { id, name } = this.props;

       fetchApartment(id, name).then(response => {
            if (response.data) {
                this.setState({ data});
            }
        });
    }
```

to use hack with promisses array and Promisse.all I should to be sure that all promisses array elements are Promisses